# how to JavaScript not shift and only tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

How can I use JavaScript to block not shift tab and allow only tab?

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".modal_container .modal_popup > .close_layer", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftkey){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".modal_container").focus();
    }
});
```

My code has <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> both working.

Comment: Well, your code is kind of working. Shift+tab still means that tab is pressed (eventually). You need to check if multiple keys are pressed at the same time, and then perfom this conditional. This way, even if you try to press any other key in combination with tab it will work, because tab will be pressed as the first or second key.

Comment: Can you post all the code?

Comment: `if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) {...}` should do what you need.